# Data van from database = ErrorException Undefined property

Tags: database, laravel

I'm using the following code to get the tag id from my database:

```
$tag_q = $this->select('id')->where('tag', '=', $tag)->get();
return $tag_q->id;
```

I've don this before in other controllers/models, but now I get:

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$id
```

Anyone knows what the problem can be?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Query Builder's method `get()` returns a collection by default.

Try looping the collection

```
foreach ($tag_q as $tag) {
    $tag->id;
}
```

If you want only one result:

```
return $this->select('id')->where('tag', '=', $tag)->first()->id;
```

Or if you want several in a an array:

```
return $this->select('id')->where('tag', '=', $tag)->get()->toArray();
```

Or also:

```
return $this->select('id')->where('tag', '=', $tag)->firstOrFail();
```